# Script doesn't work any more - repositioned a Element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to reposition an a element of a menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/kJKq6/5/

Through the lower a link it is possible to open the dropdown menu, but if the a link is positioned at the top of the html-code the menu can't be opened any more. Unfortunately it can't be used an other menu. Im new at html and php and don't know the solution, please can anyone help? Many Greetings

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">ALLE KATEGORIEN</a>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">ALLE KATEGORIEN</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on('mouseover', function () {
        $('.nav li').removeClass("open");
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
        var height = $menu.outerHeight(); var width = $menu.outerWidth();
        $('ul.' + $(this).attr("rel") + ' li > a').removeClass("maintainHover");
        $('ul.' + $(this).attr("rel") + ' li > div').hide();
        $('ul.' + $(this).attr("rel") + ' li:first-child > a').addClass("maintainHover");
        $('ul.' + $(this).attr("rel") + ' li:first-child > div').css({
            'display': 'block',
            'left': width - 3,
            'height': height - 4,
            'top': -1
        });
    });
});
</script>

<script>
var $menu = $(".dropdown-menu");
$menu.menuAim({
    activate: activateSubmenu,
    deactivate: deactivateSubmenu,
});
</script>
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle with decent spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/kJKq6/8/

Comment: You notice that the top link is not wrapped in all the other divs and lists like the second one is? And it doesn't have its own dropdown menu like the second one?

Comment: the fiddle seems to work for me in Firefox 26. not sure i see an issue.

Comment: I thought that the open function is initiated by the data-toggle function. Is there any way to place the a element on the top of the html code or an other working html-element which can trigger the a element, for example, a button? Many Greetings